# Add a Count for each button using Data Tables

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables

I am using data tables. Currently, it is working as expected, hower I would like to have the Add and Remove Buttons have some sort of count. For example AddButton_0
How would I do this using Data Tables?

```
var url = "/ClientSetup/GetCatalogueContracts";
        var contractsTable = $('#catalogueContractsTable').DataTable({
            sAjaxSource: url,
            columns: [
                { "data": "ID" },
                { "data": "Selected"},
                { "data": "Name"},
                { "data": "ContractType"},
                { "data": "StartDate"},
                { "data": "TerminationDate"},
                { "button": "Action" }
                ],
            serverSide: true,
            sDom: 't<"dt-panelfooter clearfix"ip>',
            pageLength: pageSize,
            bSort: false,
            bLengthChange: false,
            bSearch: true,
            paging: true,
            searching: true,
            order: [[2, "asc"]],
            language: {
                emptyTable: "No contracts found.",
                zeroRecords: "No contracts found.",
                info: "_START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_",
                paginate: {
                    first: "First",
                    previous: "Previous",
                    next: "Next",
                    last: "Last"
                }
            },
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: [0],
                    visible: false
                },
                {
                    targets: [1],
                    visible: false
                },
                {
                    targets: [2]
                },
                {
                    targets: [3],
                    sClass: "hidden-xs hidden-sm contractType"
                },
                {
                    targets: [4],
                    sClass: "hidden-xs fromDate"
                },
                {
                    targets: [5],
                    sClass: "hidden-xs terminationDate"
                },
                {
                    data: null,
                    targets: [6],
                    sClass: "updateTableRow text-center",
                    render: function ( data, type, full, meta )
                    {
                        var id = data["ID"];
                        return `<button class=\"btn btn-success br2 btn-xs fs12 table-btn button-selector-${id}\" id=\"AddContractBtn\">Add</button>`;
                    }
                }
            ],
            drawCallback: function( settings ) {
                disableInvalidContracts();
            },
            autoWidth: false
        });



// make sure already selected rows cannot be added again.
            var excludeIds = getExcludeIds();
            $.each(excludeIds, function() {
                var button = $("#AddContractBtn.button-selector-" + this);
                button.addClass("disabled");
                button.prop('disabled', true);
            });

        }

@* Adding and Removing Data from both Tables *@
        contractsTable.on('click', '#AddContractBtn', function () {
            var $row = $(this).closest("tr");

            @*Track Contract IDs that have been removed from the unselected table*@
            var value = $('#exclude-ids').val();
            var ids = getExcludeIds();
            ids.push($row.attr('id'));
            $('#exclude-ids').val(JSON.stringify(ids));

            var addRow = contractsTable.row($row);
            var data = addRow.data();
            data.Selected = true;
            selectedContractsTable.row.add(addRow.data()).draw( false );

            setSelectedInputForContract('true', data.ID);
            disableInvalidContracts();
        });

        selectedContractsTable.on('click', '#RemoveContractBtn', function () {
            var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var addRow = selectedContractsTable.row($row);
            var data = addRow.data();
            data.Selected = false;
            addRow.data(data);
            addRow.remove().draw();

            @* Remove the Contract ID from the exclide ids hidden input*@
            var value = $('#exclude-ids').val();
            var ids = getExcludeIds();                
            ids = ids.filter(i => i !== $row.attr('id'));
            $('#exclude-ids').val(JSON.stringify(ids));

            setSelectedInputForContract('false', data.ID);
            disableInvalidContracts();
        });
```

I am looking for a way that I can add a Count for each of the buttons for example `AddButton_0 I am unsure if there is an option to use a count on DataTables. Or whether I could use JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : you can have global variable and increment it for each access of button creation function. Click handler for add and remove button can be created with start with attribute selector in jquery.

See below code

```
var count = 0;
var url = "/ClientSetup/GetCatalogueContracts";
        var contractsTable = $('#catalogueContractsTable').DataTable({
            sAjaxSource: url,
            columns: [
                { "data": "ID" },
                { "data": "Selected"},
                { "data": "Name"},
                { "data": "ContractType"},
                { "data": "StartDate"},
                { "data": "TerminationDate"},
                { "button": "Action" }
                ],
            serverSide: true,
            sDom: 't<"dt-panelfooter clearfix"ip>',
            pageLength: pageSize,
            bSort: false,
            bLengthChange: false,
            bSearch: true,
            paging: true,
            searching: true,
            order: [[2, "asc"]],
            language: {
                emptyTable: "No contracts found.",
                zeroRecords: "No contracts found.",
                info: "_START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_",
                paginate: {
                    first: "First",
                    previous: "Previous",
                    next: "Next",
                    last: "Last"
                }
            },
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: [0],
                    visible: false
                },
                {
                    targets: [1],
                    visible: false
                },
                {
                    targets: [2]
                },
                {
                    targets: [3],
                    sClass: "hidden-xs hidden-sm contractType"
                },
                {
                    targets: [4],
                    sClass: "hidden-xs fromDate"
                },
                {
                    targets: [5],
                    sClass: "hidden-xs terminationDate"
                },
                {
                    data: null,
                    targets: [6],
                    sClass: "updateTableRow text-center",
                    render: function ( data, type, full, meta )
                    {
                        var button = `<button class=\"btn btn-success br2 btn-xs fs12 table-btn button-selector-${id}\" id=\"AddContractBtn' + count + '\">Add</button>`;
                        count++;  // increment count
                        var id = data["ID"];
                        return button;
                    }
                }
            ],
            drawCallback: function( settings ) {
                disableInvalidContracts();
            },
            autoWidth: false
        });



// make sure already selected rows cannot be added again.
            var excludeIds = getExcludeIds();
            $.each(excludeIds, function() {
                var button = $("#AddContractBtn.button-selector-" + this);
                button.addClass("disabled");
                button.prop('disabled', true);
            });

        }

@* Adding and Removing Data from both Tables *@
        contractsTable.on('click', 'button[id^=AddContractBtn]', function () {
            var $row = $(this).closest("tr");

            @*Track Contract IDs that have been removed from the unselected table*@
            var value = $('#exclude-ids').val();
            var ids = getExcludeIds();
            ids.push($row.attr('id'));
            $('#exclude-ids').val(JSON.stringify(ids));

            var addRow = contractsTable.row($row);
            var data = addRow.data();
            data.Selected = true;
            selectedContractsTable.row.add(addRow.data()).draw( false );

            setSelectedInputForContract('true', data.ID);
            disableInvalidContracts();
        });

        selectedContractsTable.on('click', 'button[id^=RemoveContractBtn]', function () {
            var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var addRow = selectedContractsTable.row($row);
            var data = addRow.data();
            data.Selected = false;
            addRow.data(data);
            addRow.remove().draw();

            @* Remove the Contract ID from the exclide ids hidden input*@
            var value = $('#exclude-ids').val();
            var ids = getExcludeIds();                
            ids = ids.filter(i => i !== $row.attr('id'));
            $('#exclude-ids').val(JSON.stringify(ids));

            setSelectedInputForContract('false', data.ID);
            disableInvalidContracts();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for sending that over. It adds a count but, it just adds a 0 to each button its not incrementing.

Comment: my bad, i have put increment after return statement and hence this will not be reachable. I have modified my code, please check

Comment: It increments the number, but when you add or remove the id should remain the same, when you add and remove.

Comment: When you add or remove, table re-draw its structure and hence render function get called again and id will be changed

Comment: Is there a way to stop it from doing that? I did think when it was something to do with re-drawing the table structure.